# Angular ui-router nested views separated templates and controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have following files:

```
index.html
car.html
truck.html

mainCtrl.js
carCtrl.js
truckCtrl.js
```

and want to make such routes:

```
#/search (template: index.html, controller: mainCtrl.js)
#/search/car (template: car.html, controller: carCtrl.js)
#/search/truck (template: truck.html, controller: truckCtrl.js)
```

index.html contains two links one which must redirect to `#/search/car` and second: `#/search/truck`

`car.html & truck.html` must load in `nested view`

Please someone help me to accomplish this task

Comment: Honestly, this question, I would **not** expect from someone experienced as you, Irakli. Please, try to create some plunker, show us where you are lost... you will get help. But this is like: Do that all instead of me....

Comment: Please provide a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have tried.

Comment: @Radim My bad please give me a minute I will update question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess something like this would do the trick.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('search', {
        url: '/search',
        controller: 'mainCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/path/to/index.html',
    })
    .state('search.car', {
        url: '/car'
        controller: 'carCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/path/to/car.html',
    })
    .state('search.truck', {
        url: '/truck'
        controller: 'truckCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/path/to/truck.html',
    })
```

Place ui-view tag somewhere in your index partial.